# MYSQL Color Coded HTML Table

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

I am working on a page that displays information from a MYSQL database. I am using some Javascript that allows the data to be sorted by column. I would like to color code by Team Number. I am wondering how to make it so that every time the team number changes the rows background color changes. I would prefer for it to alternate between two colors. The code I am using is below.

```
<?php
     echo "<center><h1>North Carolina Scouting Results</h1><table border='1' class='sortable'>
     <tr>
     <td><b>Team Number</b></td>
     <td><b>Match Number</b></td>
     <td><b>Scouter Name</b></td>
     <td><b>Robot Base</b></td>
     <td><b>Team Number</b></td>
     <td><b>Hybrid Attemted</b></td>
     <td><b>Hybrid Made</b></td>
     <td><b>Hybrid Bridge Tipped</b></td>
     <td><b>Team Number</b></td>
     <td><b>Teleop Attemted</b></td>
     <td><b>Teleop Made</b></td>
     <td><b>Balance Attempt</b></td>
     <td><b>Balance</b></td>
     <td><b>Comments</b></td>
     <td><b>Team Number</b></td>


     </tr>";
     while($record = mysql_fetch_array($db_query)){
          echo"<tr>";
          echo"<td>" . $record['team'] . "</td>";
          echo"<td>" . $record['game'] . "</td>";
          echo"<td>" . $record['name'] . "</td>";
          echo"<td>" . $record['base'] . "</td>";
          echo"<td>" . $record['team'] . "</td>";
          echo"<td>" . $record['hattempt'] . "</td>";
          echo"<td>" . $record['hmade'] . "</td>";
          echo"<td>" . $record['hbridge'] . "</td>";
          echo"<td>" . $record['team'] . "</td>";
          echo"<td>" . $record['tattempt'] . "</td>";
          echo"<td>" . $record['tmade'] . "</td>";
          echo"<td>" . $record['battempt'] . "</td>";
          echo"<td>" . $record['balance'] . "</td>";
          echo"<td>" . $record['notes'] . "</td>";
          echo"<td>" . $record['team'] . "</td>";
          echo"</tr>";
          $previous=$record['team'];
     }
     echo"</table></center>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your while loop, you could use a counter to keep track of how many times the loop has executed. Then add a style to the tr tag when the count is either even or odd.

Alternatively, you could use jquery on your page, Using the [odd selector](http://api.jquery.com/odd-selector/) to apply a style to odd numbered rows.